# Missing argument in callback function for localTodos app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Here is the source - [Todo Javascript Source](http://localtodos.com/todos.js)

addOne expects one argument

```
  this.listenTo(Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
```

as you can see here:

```
addOne: function(todo) {
  var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
  this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
},
```

where does it get this, the callback appears to call the function with no arguments?

Comment: You are passing `this.addOne` as a reference (as `listenTo` expects). This reference is then called later by the `listenTo` code. The `listenTo` code calls it with a single argument, which you don't see or need to worry about - you should just expect that function (`this.addOne`) to have one parameter

Comment: that is bizarre, it is just an event system, i did not know it feeds arguments to the callback functions

Comment: I'm confused on what you're confused about. Backbone is calling the callback (`this.addOne`) with an argument. If you're confused on what `todo` is, `console.log` it. You don't have control over the `listenTo` function, as Backbone defines it and calls the callback

Comment: Throw `console.log(arguments)` into `addOne` and you will see that it receives 3 arguments but only names one of them.

Comment: `model, collection, options` - I see it, I just was not aware that the event system called the callback with built in args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
this.listenTo(Todos, 'add', this.addOne);
```

tells you precisely *nothing* about how many arguments will be provided to the callback.

In fact, Backbone `event` callbacks receive varying numbers of params which are all cataloged here: http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

In the specific case of `add`, the callback params are `model`, `collection`, and `options`.